# parallelLevel doesn't take effect in replay function

Tags: dolphindb

I'm trying function [replay](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/replay.html) in dolphindb to replay my data in order to do some backtesting. But the parameter parallelLevel doesn't effect how fast it replays.

```
n = 30000000
quotes = table(100:0, `date`time`sym, [DATE,MINUTE,INT])
tableInsert(quotes, take(2018.12.01,n),09:30m + 1..n, 1..n)
sch = select name,typeString as type from  quotes.schema().colDefs
share streamTable(100:0, sch.name,sch.type) as outQuotes
timer replay([quotes],[`outQuotes], ,`time , ,1)
```

No matter how parallelLevel is set, it always take about 2.2 seconds to replay, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

To replay historical data in a database, we need two steps conceptually: (1) retrieve and prepare the data, and (2) stream the prepared data.

DolphinDB splits the input data to many parts so that even if the input data is huge, the system will not throw OOM. There are two pipelines behind the replay function. One retrieves small parts of data from database. The second pipeline stream the retrieved data. The parameter `parallelLevel` you mentioned is for the first pipeline only. That is, tell DolphinDB to retrieve small parts of data in parallel. This parameter will not effect the replay speed unless the bottleneck lies in data retrieval and preparation.